# Multiple images for css responsive background image - task runner

Tags: css, node.js, optimization, npm, gruntjs

I'm looking to automate css manipulation of responsive background images.

I currently have [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) set up in my project and am able to create responsive images and edit the html to show srcset, using their [responsive images tasks](http://grunt-tasks.com/responsive-images/).

The problem is that I don't have it set up for my css files and was wondering if anyone knows any working npms that can help me scan the images and add it as css media queries for creating responsive background images.

Any feedback or advice in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Best, Jonathan

Comment: Looks like a good opportunity to write your own.